# Python Dataframe contains

Tags: python

I have a two dataframes.One dataframe contains some description.Other dataframe,i have set of keywords.I want to list out the other attributes of the first data frame if the keyword from my second data frame is contained in first data frame.I tried with the below code and getting error 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

The content of Ist Dataframe is as below:

```
Name Age Sex    Job

Ed   40  M  He is a Lawyer

Aby  30  F  She is a Doctor
```

The content of IInd Dataframe is as below:

```
  Keyword    Score
   Lawyer    2.0
   Doctor    2.0
```

I want the result from Ist dataframe to print Name,Age and Sex if the Keyword from II datafarme is contained in Job column of first data frame.

I tried with the following code and it's errored out with 'str' object has no attribute 'str'.Can someone suggest a solution.

```
for i in range(0,len(df2['Keyword'])):
    for j in range(0,len(df1['job'])):
        if df1[df1['job'][j].str.contains(df2['Keyword'].values[i],na=False)]:
            print(df1.ix[j,'Name'],df1.ix[j,'Age'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change this line

```
df1[df1['job'][j].str.contains(df2['Keyword'].values[i],na=False)
```

To

```
df1[df1['job'][j].contains(df2['Keyword'].values[i],na=False)
```

Comment: If I replace str.contains with contain I get the following error: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'

Answer (score 0):

I could able to fix the issue in a different way.I converted the two dataframes into a pandas series and the using "in" parameter I retrieved the result.

for i in range(0,len(df2['Keyword'])):

```
for j in range(0,len(df1[Job'])):

    if df2.iloc[i,0] in df1.iloc[j,5]:

        print("\t Name :",df1.ix[j,'Name']," Age:",df1.ix[j,'Age'])
```